# How to mock a base class entirely when testing the derived class in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I want to test a method of a derived class in Python. The base class `__init__` function is not well-implemented for testing its derived classes, for reasons too complicated to explain. I would like to just mock the entire base class, so that the derived class inherits from the mock instead of the annoying base class.

Here is a torn-down example of the classes:

```
class ComplexAnnoyingBaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("do not execute this class in the unit test")
    def get_value_x(self):
        return 4
    def get_value_y(self):
        return 5

def calculate_value(x, y):
    return x * y

class MyDerivedClass(ComplexAnnoyingBaseClass):
    def get_value(self, min_x, min_y):
        value = 0
        x = self.get_value_x()
        y = self.get_value_y()
        if x > min_x and y > min_y:
            value = calculate_value(x, y)
        return value
```

And a simple example test:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

from server.example_code import (
    ComplexAnnoyingBaseClass,
    MyDerivedClass
)

def test_get_value():
    # Patch the base class with a mock object
    with patch('server.example_code.ComplexAnnoyingBaseClass',
               spec=MyDerivedClass) as base_class_mock:
        # Create a mock instance of the derived class
        my_instance = MyDerivedClass()

        # Mock the get_value_x() and get_value_y() methods
        base_class_mock.get_value_x.return_value = 2
        base_class_mock.get_value_y.return_value = 3

        # Test your code here
        result = my_instance.get_value(1, 1)
        assert result == 6
```

When the test ran, it printed the "do not execute" message. Also, the call to `my_instance.get_value(1,1)` returned 20.

This variation on the test also failed in the exact same ways:

```
def test_get_value():
    # Create a mock instance of ComplexAnnoyingBaseClass
    base_class_mock = Mock()
    base_class_mock.get_value_x.return_value = 2
    base_class_mock.get_value_y.return_value = 3

    # Patch the base class with the mock object
    with patch('server.example_code.ComplexAnnoyingBaseClass',
            return_value=base_class_mock):
        # Create an instance of MyDerivedClass
        my_instance = MyDerivedClass()

        # Test your code here
        result = my_instance.get_value(1, 1)
        assert result == 6
```

How do I mock the base class entirely so that its `__init__` function is not called during the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time you are calling `patch`, `MyDerivedClass` already has its own internal reference (in `MyDerivedClass.__bases__`) to the base class.

You don't need to patch that reference though; you simply need to patch `BaseClass` attributes.

```
with (patch.object(ComplexAnnoyingBaseClass, '__init__', lambda self: None),
      patch.object(ComplexAnnoyingBaseClass, 'get_value_x', lambda self: 2),
      patch.object(ComplexAnnoyingBaseClass, 'get_value_y', lambda self: 3)):

    my_instance = MyDerivedClass()

    # Test your code here
    result = my_instance.get_value(1, 1)
    assert result == 6
```

---

Replacing `ComplexAnnoyingBaseClass` in `MyDerivedClass.__bases__` is possible, but tricky. `__bases__` must be a tuple of classes, not a mock or tuple of mocks, and `patch.object(MyDerivedClass, '__bases__', (NewBase, ))` apparently tries to *remove* `__bases__` when the patch is finished before restoring the original value, and Python doesn't allow `__bases__` to be removed. You can be a bit blunter

```
MyDerivedClass.__bases__ = (NewBase,)
# test code here
MyDerivedClass.__bases = (ComplexAnnoyingBaseClass,)
```

but I recommend against such manual patching.

Comment: This answer worked for me with *python3.9*. For the benefit of others who may find this later, know that *python3.8* does not allow multiple expressions in the `with` statement. If you write the expressions as separate `with` statements, all is well.

Comment: Multiple context managers have been supported since Python 3.1. Python 3.9 added the ability to wrap multiple context managers in parentheses to allow for implicit line continuation. In 3.8 and earlier, you'd need to write `with patch.object(...), \ patch.object(...): ...` in order to break the line.

Comment: (Special support had to be added because the comma-separated list of context managers is part of the `with` statement's syntax, not just an expression sequence such as used to define a tuple.)